# Dead battery screen at usable battery percentage

Tags: macbook-pro

This is a 2020 13-inch MBP on 10.15.7.

It's already had its logic board replaced once.

I have had this issue a few times.

I keep getting the dead battery screen:

> [image]

But when I plug it in, it turns on straight away and the battery is at a usable percentage.

This time the battery was at ~54%.

The fix is simple and quick: plug it in to a socket for a second, wait for it to turn on and unplug it.

Is this a known bug? Do I have some other hardware issues that need addressing?

Comment: Take it back to Apple again.

Comment: It's hardware fault that needs to be fixed - most likely by a replacement Mac.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the battery power lines are dead. When connected to the wall power, it is bypassing the battery completely, and therefore able to turn on. I assume that the battery percentage circuitry is before the fault if the battery percentage is reporting correctly.